# How to round beta(s) in gtsummary's tbl_regression?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I just want to know how to round beta(s) column to desired number of digits.
My code:

```
tbl_regression(m, pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels()
```

I have tried estimate_fun but no success so far. Additionally I would like to ask is it a way in that regression table to mark a reference level of the factor variable or are just dashes representing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the number of digits to be displayed for the beta column using `estimate_fun=` and e.g. `estimate_fun` . The "value" to be displayed for the reference level can be set using a custom theme, i.e. via the theme option `"tbl_regression-str:ref_row_text"`. `tbl_regression` also has an argument `add_estimate_to_reference_rows=` to add a value for the reference level.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```
library(gtsummary)

m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

my_theme <-
  list(
    "tbl_regression-str:ref_row_text" = "Ref"
  )

set_gtsummary_theme(my_theme)

tbl_regression(m,
  pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2),
  estimate_fun = ~ style_number(.x, digits = 4)
) %>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.10) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @stefan, if the interaction term is included in the model, is there a reference row/level for it as well ?

Comment: Does no look like so. And I don't know whether there is an option to add a reference level for interactions.